# how to use Nextjs in cra

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I good learn react. But I know about `nextjs` I want to use this framework with `create-react-app`. How can I do? or do have solve problems SSR without `nextjs?` Where I find good simple good example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have your app with CRA (create-react-app) then you will probably need to migrate into a new next app using `npx create-next-app`.

This will create a next configuration and then you will need to migrate each component to use this new structure, this is almost straight forward here you have documentation:

https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app